# Converting java String to json object

Tags: java, json

I have a java  String  in this format

```
"{name:MyName, rage:200, height:100}"
```

and i need to convert it to JsonObject which  should be in below format

```
 {name:MyName, rage:200, height:100} // that is i want to remove the  start and end double quotes fro the above string .
```

Can some one help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the json.org library. It is as simple as `new JSONObject(s);` where s is a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Jackson JSON libraries?  [It's pretty easy to use an ObjectMapper to create a JsonNode as a tree structure and parse away from there.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JsonNode)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the quotes, using [StringUtils.mid](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#mid%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) should do your job

```
final String input = "\"{name:MyName, rage:200, height:100}\"";
final String result = StringUtils.mid (input, 1, input.length () - 2);
// result should not contain the beginning and ending quotes
```